# Bluetooth C++ Winapi Discoverable

Tags: c++, winapi, bluetooth

I'm using source codes based from the following links w/my broadcom bluetooth device:

I want to make a bluetooth server that automatically starts and other devices can pair with it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/252882/Bluetooth-Server-Programming-on-Windows
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362932(v=vs.85).aspx

I can get the code to compile fine, allegedly the server starts, it tells me my local bluetooth device, the server port,  but I cannot see the advertisement when I scan for bluetooth devices w/my iphone or ipad.

Device manager reports my bluetooth driver as functional. I'm doing this in a vm machine on win 7.

Both links say nothing about BluetoothEnableDiscovery() function. Would I need this? I tried but not sure how it works.

Everything looks ok, in the entire process I don't receive a single error. I just think I need to set it to discoverable some how or make it advertise so my other devices can see it and pair with it.

If you have any ideas, I would appreciate them. Thanks.

EDIT: Would anyone know how I can change between Secure Simple Pairing modes, or set a a 4/8 digit key for pairing in winapi c++?

Comment: Have you tried running it on the host machine instead of in a VM? Might want to eliminate the possibility of that being the cause.

Comment: Hey Captain, thanks. the driver works on the vm as I can see other devices advertisements in client mode.

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft BT stack (even with a Widcomm dongle), under Win7, your server has to expose a 'service' first.
it can be "Discoverable' but without any service exposed, no-one will "see" your server from the outside.
Check out WSASetService: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362921(v=vs.85).aspx
PS: the service will live during your app execution only...